# Sessions variable unseen in multiple pages

Tags: php, session

I don't understand the thing with sessions in php. It says that after you start a session, the session variable are stored and can be seen in multiple pages.But in my pages that are not seen. For example I have my index.php page where I start the session_start(). Then I click a button to login and if everything is ok it should redirect me to profile.php page where I print the session email. But it doesn't recognize my session variable.My code:

```
if($_POST['actiune'] == 'login'){

$email = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $email;
$password = $_POST['password'];
$pass = getPassword($email);
$verify = password_verify($password, $pass);
    if ($verify) {
        header("Location: index.php?page=profile");
    }
    else {
        header("Location: index.php?page=login&msg=PleaseRegister");
    }
}
```

profile.php

```
echo $_SESSION['username'] ; die();
```

Any help?

UPDATE:

profile.php

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 echo $_SESSION['username'] ; 

 ?>
 <div id="profile">

<p id="welcome">Welcome :<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></p>
<?php
    if ($_SESSION['avatar'] == ""){
        ?>
        <img src = "http://placehold.it/400x200/0000ff/&text=Upload a picture" alt =""/> 
        <?php
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['avatar'] != ""){
        ?>
        <img src="avatars/<?php echo $user['file'];?>">
        <?php   
    }
?>

<p id="modifyPf"><a href="index.php?page=update"> Modify</a></p>
<p id="reset"><a href="index.php?page=resetPassword"> Reset password</a></p>
<p id="articlePf"><a href="index.php?page=allArticles"> Article page</a></p>

<form action="action.scripts.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="actiune" value="avatar">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $user['id'];?>">
    <p><label for="avatar">Upload an avatar:</label></p>
    <p><input type="file" name="avatar" id="fileToUpload"></p>
    <p><input id ="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button" value="Send"/></p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `session_start();` in `profile.php` also.

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on
>   a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a
>   cookie.

**Update**

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
       session_start(); 
    } 

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
?>
        <div id="profile">
            <p id="welcome">Welcome :<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></p>
            <?php if ($_SESSION['avatar'] == ""){ ?>
                <img src = "http://placehold.it/400x200/0000ff/&text=Upload a picture" alt =""/> 
            <?php
                }
                else if ($_SESSION['avatar'] != ""){
            ?>
                <img src="avatars/<?php echo $user['file'];?>">
            <?php   
                }
            ?>
            <p id="modifyPf"><a href="index.php?page=update"> Modify</a></p>
            <p id="reset"><a href="index.php?page=resetPassword"> Reset password</a></p>
            <p id="articlePf"><a href="index.php?page=allArticles"> Article page</a></p>

            <form action="action.scripts.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" name="actiune" value="avatar">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $user['id'];?>">
                <p><label for="avatar">Upload an avatar:</label></p>
                <p><input type="file" name="avatar" id="fileToUpload"></p>
                <p><input id ="button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button" value="Send"/></p>
            </form>
        </div>
<?php
    }
    else {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
?>
```

**Index.php**

```
   <?php
        session_start();

        if($_POST['actiune'] == 'login'){
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $email;
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $pass = getPassword($email);
            $verify = password_verify($password, $pass);
            if ($verify) {
                header("Location: index.php?page=profile");
            }
            else {
                header("Location: index.php?page=login&msg=PleaseRegister");
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'POST actiune is not login';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: But it says A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in profile.php

Comment: @Adiiia You want to call it once *and only once* per request.

Comment: Now I'm more confused.

Comment: @Adiiia can you update the question and post profile.php fully.

Comment: @Adiiia see updated answer, i added `var_dump($_SESSION);` to see all the session variables set.

Comment: Ok, is not set the variable session. But how can I do to see it?

Comment: @Adiiia see updated ans. If u get the output `POST actiune is not login` it means that u are not POSTING correctly.

Comment: Thank youuu. It worked. I will look to see clearly what you did but thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

You need `session_start()` at the top of *every* <s>page</s> request - exactly one time per request. It doesn't just create the session; it's required for every request in which you want to use the session. From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

> session_start() creates a session *or resumes the current one* based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.